# How to "flag" users in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I have developed an android "Group Chat" app. Me and 20 of my friends are using this app to group chat with each other. When I look at the firebase database, I obviously see 21 users (including myself). However, I can't know whether all of them actually have the app installed on their phones, or some of them have uninstalled it. Is there any way I can differentiate among my uses? Generally speaking, can I "flag" my users as, say, *active*, *inactive*, and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question, it can be split in two parts.

First part is whether you want to know if your users are online or offline this could be achieved by an online presence system as described [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html?m=1)

The second part is whether or not users have installed or uninstalled your app. 
In my opinion easiest way to do this is by using the Firebase Analytics SDK. This way you can check the app_remove stats and whenever a user uninstalls an app, it gets updated in the console under events section.

This will give you how many devices uninstalled the app and some info on country, gender and age of the user but you could couple this with a "last login" timestamp to pinpoint the exact user.

More details along with how to include analytics SDK to your app can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001467%20%7C%20Firebase%20%7C%20Global%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20Hybrid%20%7C%20Text%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Features%20%5B2017%5D*&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-cme8r_d1wIVTF4ZCh3UYQ8vEAAYASAAEgKycvD_BwE)

Or you can use the .info/connected to have this functionality in your client code. You can read more info about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and the sample presence app at the bottom of the page will help you get a grip on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, the mere online presence system would be enough for my purpose. Just one thing, to use this system I am going to need to have a web server, right? I mean I can't rely on free tier of firebase anymore. Correct?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Firebase free tier should be more than enough for your purpose so no issue there. In order to implement the presence system there are 3 ways: 1)use the .info/connected as mentioned above 2) use firebase cloud functions to add server side logic to your app (per the blog post instructions) 3) have a separate server or just run the code to your Pc (as long as it remains on) using the Firebase server sdk.

Comment: Thanks again. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: If you are happy with answer please mark it as correct in order to help others that may have similar issues!

Comment: Sure, but how can I do that?! (Sorry, it's my first day in StackOverFlow!)

Comment: @Mohsen At the left side of the answer there are the up and down arrows and a checkmark in the middle. 
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2):

What is if you add a timestamp every time a use log in. With this timestamp you can see how long the user not log in and so if he is in active for a long time or not. It's not say if the user have delete the app. It's only a prognosis.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I record the timestamp for each user in the firebase? Is the option available?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a flag in the database as the child of the user. This flag will have an initial value of ***active***.

And instead of uninstalling the app directly, you can have a delete account functionality in the app, and whenever someone wants to delete his/her account, it simply updates the flag to ***inactive*** in firebase database.

Now you will know actually who is ***active / inactive.***

Comment: Is it possible to add a child to the user in firebase?I know How to add a child to the message, but user?

Comment: To add a child to you 'current node'. Simply use
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference('currentnode').child("users").
This will make a new child 'users' and you can add a flag as a child of the 'user' node. Its quite simple really.